# why does this regex pattern match this string?

Tags: r, regex

Pattern:

```
"d`?(?!([\\s]*<-))"
```

String:

```
"d` <-"
```

According to R, this is a match:

```
> grepl("d`?(?!([\\s]*<-))", "d` <-", perl = TRUE)
[1] TRUE
```

That doesn't make sense to me since the `d` matches, the (0 or 1) backtick matches. But the `" <-"` should not be a match?

Comment: Why do you think it should not match?

Comment: The backtick is optional, backtracking makes the regex match since `(?!([\\s]*<-))` is re-tried after `d`, and the lookahead pattern is not found immediately to the right of that location (leading to a match). What do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Due to optional match of `` `? ``, it is satisfying negative lookahead.

In PERL mode you may use this regex with a *possessive quantifier* that doesn't backtrack:

```
d`?+(?!\s*<-)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BJJjMB/2)

Here back-tick or ` is matched optionally but use of `?+` makes it possessive in nature that doesn't allow backtracking hence negative lookahead fails the match.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is backtracking, as explained in [Wiktor Stribizew's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63801817/why-does-this-regex-pattern-match-this-string/63801899#comment112822285_63801817).

Add the optional backtick into the lookahead and move the lookahead after `d`:

```
d(?!`?(\s*<-))`?
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/JPanRV/1)

**Explanation**

```
  [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2,4}                  digits (0-9) (between 2 and 4 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2,4}                  digits (0-9) (between 2 and 4 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```